# Convert OpenType (PostScript flavor) to OpenType (TrueType flavor)

Tags: fonts, typography, opentype

I want to convert a OpenType (PostScript flavor) font to an OpenType (TrueType flavor) font. This is because Office Word cannot make pdf´s using a OpenType (PostScript flavor) font. To make it more difficult, I also want to maintain the openType typography tables.

Comment: What have you done so far in pursuit of this goal — a goal that may or may not turn out to be the jackalope of font-file esoterica? Also, do you have FontLab, and/or the wherewithall to install and subsequently do battle with the GUI of [http://fontforge.org](fontforge)? I ask so I know how to best answer; best of luck either way.

Answer (score 1):

FontLab will do the trick. Hefty price tag for a one off job. Have you considered contacting the foundry you purchased from.

Answer (score 0):

[TransType](http://www.fontlab.com/font-converter/transtype/) is a software dedicated to this kind of conversions. They also have a per-day price, if you don't want to buy it.